# Nullpointerexception by changing activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, start-activity

I want to change activity with startActivity(intent), but i got a NullpointerException.

I try everything what I read in the web.

**My Code**

```
 public void starteFehler(int fall){
     Intent fehler = new Intent(this, Fehlermeldung.class);
     fehler.putExtra("fall", fall);
     startActivity(fehler);
 }
```

**LogCat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.vtas_kassenterminal, PID: 27284
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4622)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4579)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4940)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4908)
        at com.example.vtas_kassenterminal.Startbildschirm.starteFehler(Startbildschirm.java:172)
        at com.example.vtas_kassenterminal.Startbildschirm$4.onResponse(Startbildschirm.java:142)
        at com.example.vtas_kassenterminal.Startbildschirm$4.onResponse(Startbildschirm.java:128)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:83)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Here is the Fehlermedlung.class

```
public class Fehlermeldung extends AppCompatActivity {

    private long zeit;
    public int fall;
    private Handler handler;

    Parameter parameter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fehlermeldung);

        zeit = parameter.dauerFehl;

        TextView textView_meldung = findViewById(R.id.textView_meldung);
        TextView textView_id = findViewById(R.id.textView_id);
        TextView textView_loesung = findViewById(R.id.textView_loesung);

        handler = new Handler();
        final Intent startbildschirm = new Intent(this, Startbildschirm.class);

        Runnable goBack = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(startbildschirm);
            }
        };
        fall = getIntent().getIntExtra("fall", 0);
        switch (fall){
            case 0: textView_meldung.setText("Interner Fehler");
                    textView_id.setText("");
                    textView_loesung.setText("Bitte sprechen Sie das Personal am Empfang an.");
                    handler.postDelayed(goBack, zeit);
                    break;
            case -1:textView_meldung.setText("Benutzer unbekannt");
                    textView_id.setText("ID: XXXXXXX");
                    textView_loesung.setText("Bitte sprechen Sie das Personal am Empfang an.");
                    handler.postDelayed(goBack, zeit);
                    break;
            case -2:textView_meldung.setText("Chip ID bereits vorhanden");
                    textView_id.setText("");
                    textView_loesung.setText("Bitte nutzen Sie eine andere Chip ID.");
                    handler.postDelayed(goBack, zeit);
                    break;
            case -3:textView_meldung.setText("Keine Serververbindung möglich.");
                    textView_id.setText("");
                    textView_loesung.setText("Bitte versuchen Sie es zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt erneut oder sprechen das Personal am Empfang an.");
                    handler.postDelayed(goBack, zeit);
                    break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling `starteFehler()`?

Comment: I call starteFehler in a Volley Request.

Comment: Can you post `Fehlermeldung` class?

Comment: Starting an activity directly from an asynchronous operation is risky. If your `Startbildschirm` instance has been destroyed, you will crash by the time you call `startActivity()`, possibly with this exception.

Comment: I bet that you have something stupid like `new Startbildschirm().startAsyncCall()` ... but obviously you should not create new instance of class derived from `Activity`

Comment: No I do not write Startbildschirm.startAsyncCall()

Comment: Bro, i think your main thread is killed while starting other activity but i dont know why. To find out it can you post where you call `starteFehler` function?

Answer (score -1):

In this line, it seems `zeit = parameter.dauerFehl;` parameter is null.

Comment: program is not even get to this line ... exception is about calling `getApplicationThread()` on null

Answer (score -1):

I think u are not initialized Parameter class in your  Fehlermedlung.class u should intialize

Parameter parm=new Parameter ();

parm..dauerFehl;

Comment: program is not even get to this line ... exception is about calling `getApplicationThread()` on null